# Drawing triangles with recursive method c#

Tags: c#, recursion, bmp

I'm trying to create a program to draw triangles to bmp file recursevly like in the picture without System.drawing
[What i need to draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/153RG.png)

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace bMP
{

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream("result.bmp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                file.Write(
                new byte[62]
                {
                    0x42, 0x4d,
                    0x3e, 0xf4, 0x1, 0x0,
                    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0x3e, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0x28, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0xe8, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0xe8, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0x1, 0x0,
                    0x1, 0x0,
                    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0x0, 0xf4, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
                    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x0,
                    0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
                });
                int l = 128;
                var t = new byte[1000 * l];
                int triang_lenumber = l / 6;
                int max = 8;
                int deph = 3;
                Stack<int> limiter = new Stack<int>();
                limiter.Push(0);
                t = TriangleRecursive(l, ref t, triang_lenumber, 1000, max, 0.33, 0.33, ref limiter, 0, 0, deph);
                file.Write(t);
                file.Close();
            }
        }

        public static byte[] TriangleRecursive(int line_length, ref byte[] matrix, int deduction, int scale, int limit, double modx, double mody, ref Stack<int> limiter, int addx, int addy, int depth)
        {
            limiter.Push(limiter.Peek() + 1);
            if (limiter.Peek() >= depth)
            {
                limiter.Pop();
                return matrix;
            }
            int ls = line_length;
            int triang_lenumber = deduction;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = ((int)(scale * mody)) + addy; i < ((int)(scale * (mody * 2))) + addy; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i * ls + ((int)(ls * modx)) + addx + triang_lenumber; j < i * ls + ((int)(ls * (2 * modx))) + addx - triang_lenumber; j++)
                {
                    matrix[j] = 0xFF;
                }
                if (count != limit)
                    count++;
                else
                {
                    count = 0;
                    triang_lenumber--;
                }
            }
            if (limiter.Peek() < depth)
            {

                //limiter.Push(limiter.Peek() + 1);
                matrix = TriangleRecursive(ls, ref matrix, deduction / 2, scale, limit, modx / 2, mody * mody, ref limiter, addx, addy, depth);
                matrix = TriangleRecursive(ls, ref matrix, deduction / 2, scale, limit, modx / 2, mody * mody, ref limiter, ls / 2, addy, depth);
                matrix = TriangleRecursive(ls, ref matrix, deduction / 2, scale, limit, modx / 2, mody * mody, ref limiter, addx, scale * 2 / 3, depth);
                matrix = TriangleRecursive(ls, ref matrix, deduction / 2, scale, limit, modx / 2, mody * mody, ref limiter, ls / 2, scale * 2 / 3, depth);
            }

            return matrix;
        }
    }
}
```

I only get it to draw to one side, but i think that i made my code to draw to four sides and i get this:
[What i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLHlE.png)

Maybe someone can take a look and tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: You need to debug your code. Coz that we will also do. It is your code you know it better. If you are facing any technical issues you can explain.

Comment: Side note: `ref byte[] matrix` may indicate that what you are trying to do is a bit above your current understanding of the language... Not that it should discourage you to do recursion, but you may want to go back for a second and figure out what you hope to achieve/solve by using `ref`.